# Is it true that $\int{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx} = \frac{d}{dt}\int{f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I was wondering why and when is true that:
$\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\int{f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx}.$
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: See [this MathOverflow discussion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105769/counterexamples-to-differentiation-under-integral-sign)

Answer (score 2):

This is called differentiating under the integral sign. It is valid if the function in the integrand, as well as the partial you are interested in is continuous in the argument with respect to which you are integrating.

Since that was a mouthful, with your notation:
$$\int{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\int{f(x,t)\,\mathrm dx}$$
provided $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ are continuous with respect to $x$.

Edit: As mentioned in comments, this is not correct. It requires that the interval of integration be bounded by continous functions of $t$.

Comment: Well, this can't be right, since continuity isn't enough to guarantee that the partial derivative makes sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin I realized this... And have been looking around to try and fix it but can't find a precise set of conditions. Btw, I love your videos on diff forms, I've learned a ton from you. edit: I think I fixed it.

Comment: When the interval of integration is infinite, you need a uniform integrability condition on $f(x,t)$  such as $|f_x(x,t)|\leq \phi(x)$ where $\phi$ is integrable.

Comment: @qbert I think that if $f$ is continuously differentiable is enough...but maybe there is a weaker condition...

Comment: So, @AlexR. you are saying that in that case I need something like the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @FernandoSaldaña: Yep, the derivative is a limit after all.

Comment: @qbert: Thanks for the compliment. In the case of a finite interval, your corrected version is adequate. But continuity won't be enough when you have an infinite interval.